# Is there a way to get python's help() to work in the SublimeText 3 console?

Tags: sublime-text-3, python3

Sublime Text has a console which can be activated by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.  It exposes a python interpreter.  On my machine, it's python 3.3.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

However, the `help()` function does not work which is supposed to be a builtin function in python.  Attempting to call it gives this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'help' is not defined
```

Is there a way to call `help()`?

Answer (score 5):

The version of Python embedded in Sublime Text is not a completely full distribution, unlike for example the ones from python.org, Anaconda, etc. It doesn't include all modules and all functionality, and `help()` is one of the items that was dropped. The `help()` function is implemented in `pydoc.py` in a "regular" Python distribution, but I'm unsure how you would try and implement it in Sublime.

Instead of using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> console, I find it easiest to run a Python 3 interpreter inside [`SublimeREPL`](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) and do my work from there.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone ending up here from a search, importing the help function from the pydoc module seems to be working:

```
>>> from pydoc import help
```

Notably, it works with the Sublime plugin API itself, i.e.:

```
>>> help(sublime)
  ...
>>> help(sublime_plugin)
  ...
```